# Git, Github Desktop

Tags: git, github

Help!!!!! у нас есть GitHub desktop, мы комиттим там изменения, затем синхронизируем, ну или отправляем пул реквест, если форкали. В  gitBushe мы комиттим, затем пушим к себе в репозиторий и так же отправляем пул реквест. Вопрос - git и github desktop они взаимозаменяемые? или зачем мне нужен git, если я и desktop-е могу тоже самое делать?﻿ В общем я запутался

Answer (score 9):

**git** это система контроля версий, а **GitHub Desktop**  - это графический клиент для гит, ориентированный для работы с гитхабом, и работает он соответственно через гит.  поэтому без гит ты не сможешь делать тоже самое, так как клиент( GitHub Desktop) не сможет работать без самой системы контроля версий.  по сути можно этот клиент заменить на любой другой (например gitk) и работать так же как и раньше, или работать прямо из консоли, или через инструмент встроенный в ide.

Еще для информации - гитхаб -это сервер для размещения репозиториев. так вот гит напрямую с ним никак не связан. просто ребята сделали стартап для удобного размещения репов гита, а так гит репозитории можно  а иногда и нужно размещать на своих серверах. как альтернатива для гитхаба есть еще гитлаб , битбакет, и другие удобные сервисы для размещения репозиториев.

Надеюсь более-менее понятно разъяснил.

Comment: А каким образом клиент работает через git? просто смотрел видеоурок, там в первой части он просто с консоли вводил команды, а во втором ничего не подключая мы просто открыли клиент и практически тоже самое проделали, только более удобным способом! Ну то есть, как понять клиент не сможет работать без системы контроля версий, мы же её не подключали или он уже в себя включает её? надеюсь тоже понятно спросил) и по итогу, можно работать или через консоль или через клиент дело вкуса?

Comment: @ШаховГлеб,  последний вопрос  я ответил выше, в ответе,  а про встроенный гит -то нет встроенного. можно проверить двумя способами - тупо удалить гит из OS или (и я это сделал) - покопаться в исходниках программы. в общем все работает через child_process.execFile  и через child_process.spawn, предварительно найдя  гит  в OS. (если решишь удалить гит из ос- делаешь все на свой страх и риск).  А выше перечисленные команды подключаются к  потоку в ос и запускают процессы с теми же аргументами и командами,если ты ты делал это руками.

Comment: Для тех кто в танке (это я про себя). Может я не совсем корректно задал вопрос. Есть 2 варианта работы с git, первый, это работа с gitbush(консолью), второй - через интерфейс этой консоли github, верно?

Comment: ну блин...я уже начинаю терять связь с действительностью...))) git работает в потоке оси и не имеет графического интерфейса. для удобства, для его делают  надстройки графические- например гитхаб десктоп или другие. но эти графические надстройки работают все равно с уже установленным в ос гитом. и поэтому ты можешь работать  как душе угодно , ничего не изменится, но при этом надстройки удобнее.  еще удобнее использовать встроенные в ide интерфейсы для работы с гитом. что значит через интерфейс консоли?  консоль это просто одна из форм общения пользователя с ос.

Comment: Вот оно, спасибо. Просто я только учусь, так что не сердчай на глупые вопросы и спасибо за терпение и объяснение) теперь все понятно)

Comment: @ШаховГлеб я ещё свои 5 копеек вставлю, если позволите. Github Desktop не работает под линуксом (по этому не каждому подойдёт), но кроссплатформенных альтернатив у него куча, GitKraken, например. Вы можете также подключаться к гитхабу и через IDE, вроде Атома или VSCode. Вариантов много, тут кому как удобно. Но самый удобный вариант всё же консольный, потому что он универсальный и вы можете автоматизировать свои задачи через скрипты.